# Why should we use the literal {} instead of new object()

Tags: javascript

I have a Question with answer, But i want to know the  reason.

There are two types to declare an object in javascript.

```
var test = {} // literal method

var test = new object();
```

Here the best best method I found in all the site is literal method. But I want to know the reason for why literal method in the best??

Comment: but my question not answered

Comment: Sure it is. Read the duplicate question. Understand the answers. As your question stands right now, they answer it. If they don't, elaborate on your question.